# VBA insert formula with dynamic cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating subtotals and would like to have in the empty cells (no sum) of the subtotal line reference the cell above. The formula would reference the cell above. For example: if row 4 is the subtotal line and cell A4 is an empty cell than I was the formula in A4 to read "=A3"

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Cells(-1, "A").Address(False, False)
```

I have the above code written but I get Run-time error 1004 Application -defined or object defined error.

I have also tried the code below but error out as well.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Cells(-1, A).Address(False, False)
```

Comment: Change the `"A"` to the column number `1`.

Comment: And there is no row at -1 cells is not relative to active cell but the parent. In this case the active sheet. You are looking for r1c1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the offset to reference a cell relative to another.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
```

if the activecell is A4 then the offset refers to A3. use `.Address` property to get the address you need in a formula. for example:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address
```